# Could you tell me I can find specification of protocol PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Could you tell me I can find specification of protocol PostgreSQL? Version 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Protocol versions 2 and 3 are described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html). For version 1, you'd have to look at the documentation of really old releases.

Comment: I'm reading this https://www.pgcon.org/2014/schedule/attachments/330_postgres-for-the-wire.pdf to understand message flow and protocol of PostgreSQL.  I wanna ensure this document is up to date with protocol version 3.0. I'm gonna read this carefully.

Comment: The wire protocol hasn't changed since 2014 (else it wouldn't be version 3 any more).